# Failure in Rails Tutorial (Hartl) -section 7 - "unkown attribute: password"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've searched this issue on the forum and have used a solution on the spork site to remove "--drb" from spec options, got it to load and run and still this persistent error keeps popping up.  I've also run it without spork.  I've read ahead on a bunch of rspec info and as stated dug through spork info, but nothing yet. I've also ran checks for typos, indentation, encoding... and am at a loss still.  Other issues, I've been able to fix, but this one's got me.  Here it is below if anyone has a suggestion:

Failures:

1) User password encryption has_password? method should be false if the passwords don't match
     Failure/Error: @user = User.create!(@attr)
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: password
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:94:in `block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 0.836 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
  <-- Slave(1) run done!

Answer (score 8):

are you certain you have added :password as a virtual attribute on your User model? It's easy to miss but you need to include the line

```
attr_accessor :password
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I just went through everything and found it.  Absolutely correct!

Comment: hey Graham can you explain why attr_accessor :password is necessary when we have attr_accessible :password. It definitely works but I just don't understand why

Comment: the attr_accessor sets up password as a virtual attribute on the model and also the access methods to it (get and set). The attr_accessible is slightly different as that states whether the property is accessible from outside of the model. If you look at some of the other attributes on the model these aren't visible outside of it (the encrypted_password and salt attributes are good examples of this) which means the controller can do nothing with them, only the model knows about them (and should).

Comment: Thanks much for this. Spend hours figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this has changed between the time the question was asked (2011) and now, but I initially ran into the same issue -- I'd added all of the tests for password etc, and the User initialization itself was failing across the board with "unknown attribute: password".

On the face of it, GrahamJRoy's answer (and more importantly, subsequent comment of elaboration) addressed my confusion perfectly.

However, I then kept reading the next section of the tutorial and learned that the following line in the User model implies the same thing:

```
has_secure_password
```

Once I added this, I no longer needed the explicit attr_accessor declaration:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
```

My only complaint with the tutorial here is that Michael doesn't warn you that ALL of your User references will begin to fail if you add the :password and :password_confirmation to User.new() when the tutorial first shows you the updated constructor. I was expecting only the new tests to fail, thought I was off-track, and so searched elsewhere (such as here) for a solution before continuing the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change `attr_accessible` to `attr_accessor` in `models/user.rb`

I made the same mistake and overlooked it.